# Threading issue with Dispatcher.invoke in WinRT

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, windows-runtime

I posted a question some time ago on [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/0f787059-7695-4666-a69d-41fcc41c10d2) involving the following code. It creates on a new thread, reads thumbnail from a file and displays it through Dispatcher.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async()=>{
            var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; ;

            var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(".txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            var t = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.DocumentsView);
            //Some proccessing....
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,(a,b)=>{
                var bmp = new BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(t); //Exception here
                image.Source = bmp;
            }, this, null);
            //Some more stuff...
        });
    }
```

*image* is just an Image control in the XAML

I get a big exception if above code executes. The exception occurs at `bmp.SetSource(t)`.

Here is full exception info:

> Transition into COM context 0x1347668 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper
> failed with the following error: An outgoing call cannot be made since
> the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)). This is
> typically because the COM context 0x1347668 where this
> RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been disconnected or it is busy
> doing something else and cannot process the context transition. No
> proxy will be used to service the request on the COM component and
> calls will be made to the COM component directly. This may cause
> corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all
> COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for
> context transition, until the application is completely done with the
> RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live
> inside them.

Switching from using Invoke to InvokeAsync fixes the problem, but I'm wondering why. Can someone explain?

EDIT: Above is just some test code. The Task I created is meant to simulate execution under a non-UI thread context which occurs in my app since it need to both read files and update UI from a none-UI thread context.

Comment: It is a fugly COM threading problem.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the thumbnail object being owned by a temporary thread.  The point of using async/await is so you don't have to use a Task.  Just dump it and then you don't have to invoke either.

Comment: Btw, I strongly suggest using Dispatcher.RunAsync instead of Dispatcher.Invoke/InvokeAsync - RunAsync is designed to work well with C#'s async infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand the reason for the `Task` inside the click handler given that you just end up invoking it on UI thread anyway.

```cs
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
  var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(".txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
  var t = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.DocumentsView);
  var bmp = new BitmapImage();
  bmp.SetSource(t); //Exception here
  image.Source = bmp;
}
```

Comment: The code I posted is just some test code. The Task was to simulate none-UI context which happens in my app. The app needs to do read file thumbnail and display it within a callback from a custom WPD driver routed through a WinRT C++ Component DLL.

Comment: @Xiao - The easy solution is still the same, just await _that_ task and then update the thumbnail.